# Django regex - optional grouped parameters

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'm constructing the urlconf for a website but I'm facing a couple of issues;

At some point I have to present a list of tasks which can eventually be reordered. The problem is that I have no clue on how to go about configuring the regex.

So far I've got this:

```
url(r'^myapp/mytasks, myview.tasks),
```

The default behavior is to accept requests at `www.mydomain.com/myapp/mytasks`.

However should the order button be pressed by a user, I need Django to also accept requests of type:

`www.mydomain.com/myapp/mytasks/sort_by/price_highest`
`www.mydomain.com/myapp/mytasks/sort_by/price_lowest`

but not

`www.mydomain.com/myapp/mytasks/price_lowest`

Is there a regex for this scenario?

Thank you all in advance.

P.S
Ideally I would also like to know how I could possibly reverse them.

Comment: try `url(r'^myapp/mytasks/sort_by', myview.tasks),`

Comment: @AvinashRaj This won't work for the default scenario: `www.mydomain.com/myapp/mytasks`.

Comment: For options such as sorting, I'm more inclined to use a query string such as `www.mydomain.com/myapp/mytasks?sort_by=price_highest`, or even `www.mydomain.com/myapp/mytasks&sort_by=price&reversed=false`. You'd then have to process the query string inside the view.

Comment: @Konos5 try `url(r'^myapp/mytasks(?!/price_lowest)',  myview.tasks)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks but I think you are missing the point here. It's not that I need everything except `price_lowest`. I need `price_lowest` or `price_highest` or whatever other parameter comes to my mind but only after `/sort_by/` exists. If `sort_by` is absent, discard all and revert to default.

Comment: like `url(r'^myapp/mytasks(?:/sort_by.*)?', myview.tasks),` . Don't know much about django..

Answer (score 1):

Create two `url` records for the same view:

```
url(r'^myapp/mytasks/$', myview.tasks, name='tasks'),
url(r'^myapp/mytasks/sort_by/(price_highest|price_lowest)/$', myview.tasks,
                                                   name='sorted_tasks'),
```

And then change the signature of the `tasks()` view to:

```
def tasks(request, sort_by=None):
    ...
```

In the template you can easily point to the both versions:

```
{% url 'tasks' %}
{% url 'sorted_tasks' 'price_highest' %}
```

**UPDATE**: If you really want to make the only one `url` record then the regex will be:

```
'^myapp/mytasks/(?:sort_by/(price_highest|price_lowest)/)?$'
```

But I am not sure that it will work with `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the multiple url records. However I need to do this in a single url record using only regex so I can easily reverse it in my templates.

Comment: What is the problem with reversing of two urls?  See the updated answer.

Comment: As you put it... there is no problem and your solution seems to be working perfectly fine. However it is a matter of personal preference. And I would really like to see this tricky regex that would accomodate my problem.

Comment: The regex is not so tricky but I never used something like this in `url` and not sure that the reverse for this regex will work.  You can test it if you want.  See the updated answer.